# Two Way binding in Rich Text Box Not Working

Tags: wpf

I have a Binding to the Rich Textbox and for that I have created an helper. I am binding to a single class property. Below are the code and samples :

This is the Helper i have created :

```
public class RichTextBoxHelper
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Text Attached Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(RichTextBoxHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((string)null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, 
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged),
                new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceText),
                true,
                UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Text property.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetText(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the Text property.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetText(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the Text from a FlowDocument
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="document">The document to get the text from</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a string with the text of the flow document</returns>
    public static string GetText(FlowDocument document)
    {
        return new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd).Text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles changes to the Text property.
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox textBox = (RichTextBox)d;
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            textBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
            textBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(e.NewValue.ToString())));
        }
    }

    private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object value) 
    {
        return value ?? "";
    }
```

The code in XAML is this :

```
<RichTextBox Name="txtView" 
                                                     AcceptsReturn="False" 
                                                     Grid.Column="2" 
                                                     Grid.Row="5" 
                                                     BorderThickness="0" 
                                                     Margin="2,5,5,2" 
                                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                                     local:RichTextBoxHelper.Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ItemData.Description}">
```

The Selected item in my View model is this :

```
public DataDetail SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedItem = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

The Structure of the DataDetail class and nested properties is as follows :

```
public class DataDetail
{
    public ItemData ItemData { get; set; }
    // Other properies (other class objects 
}

public class ItemData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    // Other properties (string and int, float)
}
```

The problem is that the data into the Richbox is read from this property, but when i try to change anything in that Richtextbox (in UI), it doesnot go into the property. The same thing works when i bind the Name property to a textbox and that works (Read and update back) just by specfying this in XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ItemData.Name}"></TextBox>
```

What is the issue in Richtext box ?

Any help is appreciated.

- Girija

Answer (score -2):

How would the property *know* that it changed? There is no description telling it that it is supposed to correspond to the contents of a paragraph in the RichTextBox. You would need to observe all changes to the contents of the RichTextBox and their Text properties and manually [change the current value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) for your attached Text property.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate what you mean ?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate what you mean ?

Comment: @Shankar: No, i *cannot*. It really should not be that hard to understand, two way binding only does something to the source if the **target changes the property**, and here it doesn't.